# How to add BLOB data into my SQL command

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I use **System.Data.SQLite** library for working with databse file, avoiding any specific class names connected with that library, using interface names. e.g. `IDbConnection = new SQLiteConnection`, and etc.

So Instead of `SQLiteCommand` i have `IDbCommand` interface instance.
The problem that i want to add **BLOB** data into my command and i cannot do this, as  `IDbCommand.Properties.Add()` has no *suitable* implementation for me - it only accepts `object` parameter.

I cannot use `SQLiteCommand` class name explicitly, so i need to find some proper way to do as in example i've found (http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_read_write_blob.html):

```
sqliteCommand.Parameters.Add("@Photo",    
    SqlDbType.Image, photo.Length).Value = photo;
```

Why do i do like this? In future, i probably will use my code for remote SQL connections, not just SQLite.... Really need to find some solution...

Thank you!

Comment: What is the type of `photo`? is it a `byte[]` ? Also: do you mean `IDbCommand.Parameters.Add()`?

Comment: @Marc Gravell, of course, as i am talking about blobs, this code sample is from link mentioned in text. 2) yes

Comment: "blobs" is vague, hence why I wanted to be clearer. There are often vendor-specific blob types that can be used.

Comment: Well... Hope it's not too different.. as i understand it's just a byte data and its length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically:

```
IDbDataParameter param = cmd.CreateParamter();
param.ParameterName = "@Photo";
param.Value = blob;
param.Size = blob.Length;
param.DbType = DbType.Binary;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```